# Why is a Harmonic distribution a function?

Tags: distribution-theory

I want to know how one proves: 
``If for a distribution $T$ it holds that $\Delta T$=0, then $T$ is an Harmonic function (see [Page in the book of Donoghue with the Theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NMhS.png))''.

In the proof in this book I do not understand the last sentence, can someone explain this: ``It follows that $S$ is a $C^\infty$-function in the ball...''

(How does it follow from the convolution $E_1 * \Delta S =0$ in that ball that $S$ is a $C^\infty$ function in that ball?)

With a distribution in this case is meant a linear functional on $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)$ (e.g., not a tempered distribution).

Comment: Hmmm, you have $S=E_1\ast \Delta S + E_2\ast\Delta S$ where the latter is a $C^\infty$-function and the first is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Since differential operators are "local", even on distributions, we can multiply a given harmonic distribution by a smooth cut-off function so that it is compactly supported, hence tempered, and satisfies $\Delta u=f$ with $f$ another compactly-supported distribution, identically $0$ on a large ball. Then everything in sight is a tempered distribution, so Fourier transforms can be used...

Comment: I was actually looking for an argument that does not use tempered distributions (in the book, tempered distributions and Fourier transforms of them are introduced later so there should be an argument using only preceding theorems in the book). 
Mathematically it solves the problem, thank you. 
Indeed; in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1679551/show-that-the-only-tempered-distributions-which-are-harmonic-are-the-the-harmoni is explained how to continue.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: As is commented by Vobo, actually there is no problem (I just overlooked it). The claim follows from the equality $S= E_1 * \Delta S + E_2 * \Delta S$.

Longer comment on the answer: So basically there are multiple points of view on the statement. One can prove that a Harmonic distribution is a Harmonic function without any knowledge of Tempered distributions or Fourier transforms. However, with this knowledge - as is commented by Paul Garrett - one can prove a little bit more. In case $T$ itself is tempered one can actually prove that $T$ is a polynomial (see e.g. [Show that the only tempered distributions which are harmonic are the the harmonic polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1679551/show-that-the-only-tempered-distributions-which-are-harmonic-are-the-the-harmoni)).

Indeed, one proves that the support of $\mathcal F(T)$ (the Fourier transform of $T$) is $\{0\}$, which then implies that $\mathcal F(T)= \sum_{\alpha : |\alpha| \le k} c_\alpha \partial^\alpha \delta_0$. Applying the Fourier inverse we find that

$T= \sum_{\alpha :|\alpha|\le k} d_\alpha x^\alpha $

(as $\mathcal F \mathbb 1 = \delta_0$, and $\mathcal F x^\alpha = (-1)^\alpha \delta^\alpha$), where $d_\alpha = (-1)^\alpha c_\alpha$.